# End a program after meeting user entered sum in Python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, sum

```
total = 0
not_total = True
sum_of_square = int(input("Enter desired sum: "))

while (not_total == True):
        for n in range (2): 
        total = total + n**2
        print("The sum of squares from 1^2 to {0}^2 is equal to {1}.".format(n,total))
```

This will provide an infinite amount of sums but I want to stop the total sum before the user input

Answer (score 0):

You can just compare the two values in the conditional statement of the while loop like so:

```
total = 0
sum_of_square = int(input("Enter desired sum: "))

while (sum_of_squares <= total):
        for n in range (2): 
        total = total + n**2
        print("The sum of squares from 1^2 to {0}^2 is equal to {1}.".format(n,total))
```

Comment: I tried that piece of coding but it came back as an infinite loop but I tried putting an if statement like this...

    total = 0
    not_total = True
    sum_of_square = int(input("Enter desired sum: "))

    while (not_total == True):
        for n in range (1,100,1): 
            total = total + n**2
            if total < sum_of_square:
                print("The sum of squares from 1^2 to {0}^2 is     equal to {1}.".format(n,total))
            else:
                not_total = False'

but I want to somehow change that 100 into an infinite number

Comment: You may be going over the total. I updated the code, try that.